# Codeigniter 3 - how to add option with possible select template

Tags: codeigniter-3

I've created table in database:

```
general_settings -> template ->  layout01
```

in storefront dropdown with possible select layout01, layout02, layout03 etc with post value to database.

and now styles, js etc:

```
assets/frontend/layout01
assets/frontend/layout02
assets/frontend/layout03
```

etc.

and currently I can only load one template layout01 example like this:

in

```
application/views/index.php
application/views/partials/_header.php
application/views/partials/_footer.php
```

and in Home_Controller.php I call this like this:

```
public function index()
{
    

    $this->load->view('partials/_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
    $this->load->view('partials/_footer');
}
```

1. How to load styles and _header.php, _footer.php and all others pages depending on  value in database layout01, layout02 etc?

Answer (score 0):

In the header and footer files make a simple function call which you can do in helper with a readdir/scandir etc. In the header you load the assets/frontend/$selected_layout/*.css files, while in the footer you load the assets/frontend/$selected_layout/*.js files.

application/helper/loadResources_helper.php

```php
<?php
function loadResources($layout, $type)
{
    $files = [];
    $rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./assets/frontend/'.$layout.'/'));
    foreach ($rii as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()){
            continue;
        }
        $ext = $file->getExtension();
        if($type == $ext) {
          $files[] = $file->getPathname();
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

then we load the helper for automatic loading
application/config/autoload.php

```php
$autoload['helper'] = array('...','....','loadResources');
```

application/views/partials/_header.php

```php
foreach(loadResources($selected_layout, 'css') as $stylesheet) {
 echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$stylesheet.'" />';
}
```

application/views/partials/_footer.php

```php
foreach(loadResources($selected_layout, 'js') as $javascript) {
 echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$javascript.'"></srcipt>';
}
```

```sql
$selected_layout = your SQL query for general_settings -> template -> layoutXX
```